# Tcl Quick Reference

Tags: tcl

I am new to tcl and I am looking for a 2 page quick reference that I can hang up next to my computer.  I know that 2 page quick references are pretty common and readily available for many programming languages, but I'm having trouble finding one that is both concise (<= 2 pages) and up to date (>= version 8.5).  Any help finding this would be appreciated.

-edit-

To be more specific, [This One](http://alpha.tmit.bme.hu/meresek/tcl2.pdf) is exactly the format and length that I desire, but this one is out of date because it is based on version 7.3.  I will probably end up using this one until something better is created or found.

Comment: This isn't what you asked for, but I keep http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm and http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html open in browser tabs when coding Tcl. Most things I want are a click or two from those two pages, and Google finds the rest easily enough for me. :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. [Minimalist](http://www.pkturner.org/programming/Tcl_cheat_sheet.html)
2. [More Verbose](http://www.rkeene.org/projects/info/resources/tcl/docs/tcl-tk-reference-guide.pdf)

Comment: #1 one is too short, and #2 is way too long.  Neither of these fall within my constraints.

Comment: Then you should probably just take all you want from both of em and make one for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://home.comcast.net/~brian199/tcl_tk_ref_guide.html) is quite a nice one, concise but fairly complete and up-to-date.

Comment: This is too long (not suitable for printing), and does not fall within my constraints.  Thanks though.